# C String cropping runtime error

Tags: c, pointers, char

I want to have a function that returns me `k`-th word from string `str`.

```
char* word_at(int k, char* str)
{
    char *p;

    for (p = str; *p != '.'; p++)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            char *end_of_word;
            end_of_word = strchr(p, ' ');
            *end_of_word = '\0';
            return p;
        }
    if (*p == ' ')
        k--;
    }
}
```

So i want to crop the string after k-th word and return pointer to the beginning of this word.

The problem is i cannot put the `'\0'` to the `str`.
Visual Studio 2015 and 2012 fires me Access violation exception.
Can anybody help me?

**UPD**

I try to run it with correct input data:

```
printf("%s\n", word_at(2, "The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog."));
```

Comment: Maybe `strchr(p, ' ');` returns NULL and you dereference it? Add a test for NULL.

Comment: Trying to change a string literal as you do is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in this function:

- You assume there is a space after the word and do not check if `end_of_word` might be `NULL`. Chances are `*end_of_word = '\0';` will trigger the violation in this case.
- You loop forever testing only for `'.'`.  If you read past the end of the string, you might dereference invalid addresses, triggering the violation.
- If you pass a string literal to this function, modifying it may also trigger a violation.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I should gave an example of using my function.
But 
1. while debugging `end_of_word` isn't NULL
2. My sentence ends with `.`
-I do not modify my `str`

Comment: You may not be aware that you **do** modify `str` here: `*end_of_word = '\0';`

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `word_at()`?  I strongly suspect you pass a string literal.  String literals are stored in a read only segment at run time, writing to them causes an access violation.

Comment: Yes, it's that. I call `word_at(2, "The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog.")`. I have to path `str` as a string variable, not as a string literal. And then i can change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking for the end of the string (and trying to read after it's buffer): `for (p = str; *p != '.'; p++)` tries to read until a dot is found, but does not check for the end of the "string". Also `strchr(p, ' ')` could return `NULL`, indicating, that there is no space in the string starting in `p`.

Try `for (p = str; *p != '\0' && *p != '.'; p++)` and add a check that you do not dereference `NULL` after `strchr(p, ' ')`.

Updated: Trying to change a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Yes, you are totally right to check that. But in my case i try with correct input data and it crashes on `*end_of_word = '\0';`